# laravel | eloquent foreach not working

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to retrieve all non admin users from my user table.
like so

```
$agents = User::where('is_admin','=', 'false')->get();

//didn't work
foreach ($agents as $agent=>$value) 
{
    echo "{$agent}=>{$value}"."<br>";
}

//tried dumping
dd($agents);
```

but It didn't work so I tried dumping the variable to check if it had any results, I have one non-admin as of now: and here is the output

```
Collection {#219 ▼
#items: array:1 [▼
    0 => User {#222 ▼
      #casts: array:1 [▶]
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▶]
      #original: array:10 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please Help

Comment: what do you want to print out...you are returning a collection here....how many non admin users do you have in your table? And you can't echo the collection, echo is used only for simple stuff, strings and ints and such

Comment: @lewis4u I'm trying to get details of all non-admins. I currently have one non-admin but that number will grow. I want to print them using foreach

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$agents = User::where('is_admin','=', 'false')->pluck('value', 'agent'); 

foreach ($agents as $agent=>$value) {
echo "{$agent}=>{$value}"."<br>";
}
```

Using pluck you will convert the object to a array, so you can use the foreach the way you want with the `key => value`.

If you need to access other attributes of the model, you will need to do something like this:

```
$agents = User::where('is_admin','=', 'false')->get(); 

foreach ($agents as $agent) {
echo "{$agent->id}=>{$agent->name}"."<br>";
}
```

This way you just need to use `$agent` and `->` followed by the attribute you want.

Comment: Using pluck returns a collection, not an array. (From Laravel version 5.3^)

Comment: @lewis4u it will return the collection with an array instead of a collection with objects.

Comment: @BigBoss Your method worked though I had to pass field names specifically inside pluck. Is there anyway to pluck all fields without specifying them in pluck?

Comment: @SapneshNaik all fields are there. you just need to show them....like {{ $agent->name }}, {{ $agent->address }} make a table or some bootstrap grid

Comment: Thank you Bigboss and  @lewis4uI, finally got it

Comment: @lewis4u he point it out that he is just trying it out so he can set up the view with the proper data.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should be like:

```
public function index() {

    $agents = User::where('is_admin','=', 'false')->get();
    return view('viewfile', compact('agents'));
}
```

And then in that view file make the foreach loop in blade view

```
@foreach ($agents as $agent)
     {{ $agent->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am trying to pass the variable to a view after I confirm it prints as intended in my controller(which is using foreach)

Comment: Yup will try that, I was just trying to make sure I have correct data before I pass it to my view. I wonder why it doesn't work in controller?

Comment: try with print_r() in controller, or var_dump()

Answer (score 0):

Here `$agents` is a `Std Class object array`. so access it elements try this:

```
foreach ($agents as $agent) 
{
    $agent->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to echo information about all non-admins:

```
$agents = User::where('is_admin','=', 'false')->get();

foreach ($agents as $agent) 
{
    foreach($agent as $property => $value) {
        echo "{$property} => {$value}"."<br>";
    }
    echo "<br/>----------------------<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you have a query like `$items = items::all();` but then you want a specific value from the collection, like `$items->barcode`?

When trying dd($items) the items are returned in an array form, which require for me to know each ID in order to get the appropriate result `($items[id]->barcode)`.

I am guessing the answer would be having a foreach loop?